# Powershell - Issues to test a value in a list

Tags: powershell, if-statement, testing

I have a 2 variables:

```
$Listgivenname = Get-aduser -filter * | Select-Object givenname 
$Usergivenname = "Tom"
```

Actually, Tom is in `$Listgivenname`, so I decided to make an `if` statement like:

```
If($Listgivenname -contains $Usergivenname) {Write-Host "blablabla"}
```

But actually this command outputs `false`, even with `$Usergivenname -in $Listgivenname`.

The weird part comes when I choose to manually write the list in `$Listgivenname`, like "Tom", "Jerry". It actually works, so I believe there's a thing that I need to understand about a command witch I assign to a variable.

`Get-aduser -filter * | Select-Object givenname` doesn't seem to work like a manually written list.

I don't ask for solutions but I'm trying to understand why this happens.

Comment: You have to expand the property: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty givenname`.

Comment: Hello, a big thanks to you it work, i'll look for -ExpandProperty, thanks again

Comment: `$Listgivenname` is an array of objects and each object has the property `GivenName`, by using `-ExpandProperty GivenName` or `$Listgivenname.GivenName` you get the values of each object which is something `-contains` can compare (an array of strings)

Comment: Note that `-contains` only matches whole array elements.

Comment: You can also write `(Get-aduser -filter *).givenname` to get the name property of all users directly, without `Select-Object`. This returns an array of all user names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add `-ExpandProperty` (to get the values of each object):

```
$Listgivenname = Get-aduser -filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty givenname
```